# T-SQL inserting data into table with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, alter-table

I'm using SQL Server 2014 to create and insert data into tables and came along a problem when it comes to populating a table with a foreign key constraint in it. I have a table `user` and and a table `city` which were created beforehand.

I used code to alter the `user` table to include a `cityId` foreign key from table `city` with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE [Schema].[user]
    ADD cityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL            
    CONSTRAINT usr_cid_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (cityId) REFERENCES [Schema].[city] (cityId);
GO
```

Basically I modified the user table by adding a field called `cityId` which i made foreign key. now the problem is that when inserting data, in the first line

```
 INSERT INTO [Schema].[user](name, surname, dob, gender, .. )
```

`cityId` cannot be found to be mapped. Dunno why it ain't showing. In the design view it is listed as a foreign key so there should be no problems.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are `City` table empty?

Comment: City was filled with a couple of data and was successful

Comment: Check the type of cityid on Alter statment - `Number Not null`

Comment: _"cityId cannot be found to be mapped"_ - what is the error message?

Comment: it just doesnt come up in intellicense as a field in user table

Comment: Try to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
ALTER TABLE [Schema].[user]
ADD cityId NUMBER NOT NULL           
CONSTRAINT usr_cid_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (cityId) REFERENCES [Schema].[city] (cityId);
```

**Note :**

For `ADD cityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL`

By the SQL standard, a foreign key must reference either the primary key or a unique key of the parent table. If the primary key has multiple columns, the foreign key must have the same number and order of columns. Therefore the foreign key references a unique row in the parent table; there can be no duplicates.

Comment: atm i have 

CREATE TABLE [Schema].[city](

 cityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
   CONSTRAINT cty_pk PRIMARY KEY
   DEFAULT NEWID()        -- GUID - Globally Unique Identifier
 , cityName NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT cty_cn_un UNIQUE      
);


so i have to make the id of city as number data type too i guess right?

Comment: Identity field should be numeric